# How to use configmap in openshift to read activemq.xml

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, activemq-classic, scheduler, configmap

I am new to openshift/k8s. I have a requirement to enable schedulerSupport in ActiveMQ container.

**Current config:**

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" "brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
```

**I want the new config like this:**

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">"
```

I am trying to achieve this using configmap, and I have created the configmap like this but I am facing issue while mapping into my existing deployment config.

```
oc create configmap amqconfig --from-file=activemq.xml
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Thanks @Justin I am trying to achieve this in my existing deployment config but from config map it not taking the amq.xml

refer my complete deployment config in below URL, something I  am missing need your guidance on this.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anishkumarvalsalam/deploymentconfig/main/README.md











valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: amqconfig
                  key: activemq.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the config map into the file system for the pods, see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-configmaps.html#nodes-pods-configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-volumes_configmaps.

Comment: Thanks @johan I am trying to achieve this in my existing deployment config but from config map it not taking the amq.xml

refer my complete deployment config in below URL, something I  am missing need your guidance on this.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anishkumarvalsalam/deploymentconfig/main/README.md











valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: amqconfig
                  key: activemq.xml